# Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status when using Authentication in Header

Tags: iis, cors, axios, preflight

I have deployed a .Net Core Applicaition in an ISS Server. In client site I have a React Application using axios to communicate with the server.

On server this is how I modified the web config

```
<httpProtocol>
            <customHeaders>
                <remove name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Credentials" value="true" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost:3000" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="Origin, X-Requested-With, Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Authorization" />
                <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="86400" />
            </customHeaders>
        </httpProtocol>
```

On the client

```
const getRequestConfig = async (): Promise<AxiosRequestConfig> => {
  let accessToken = await OAuth2Service.getInstance().GetAccessToken();
  return {
    headers: {
      Authorization: `Bearer ${accessToken}`
    },
    withCredentials: true
  };
};

let config = await getRequestConfig();
    const response = await axios.get(
      `https://myserver/AppService/api/metadata/office`,
      config
    );
```

I get a preflight CORS error

> Access to XMLHttpRequest at
>   'https://myserver/AppService/api/metadata/office' from origin
>   'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to
>   preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have
>   HTTP ok status.

If I remove the authentication from the request header it will pass CORS since it is a simple request.

1. Do I miss some configuration on server site or on client site?
2. Can it be that only in localhost this problem exists and when the site is deployed will pass CORS? In that case I could disable CORS in my browser.

Comment: Please don't use your own custom response headers, but IIS CORS module, https://blogs.iis.net/iisteam/getting-started-with-the-iis-cors-module

Comment: Thanks @LexLi, I removed them. As I explained in my answer, the were not needed any more.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying to fix the issue inside the config file. I realized that the problem was that the .NET Core App. First of all the application needs to work. If the application crashes in the server after deployment you get a CORS problem in the client without any explanation. And the you need to setup CORS inside the startup file of the server app. After republishing the app and removing all the custom headers as well as the `withCredentials` in the client, I was able to pass the Bearer token without getting any preflight CORS error.